# Method is not showing in stack trace in production

Tags: c#, extension-methods, stack-trace

I have a method call sequence like this:

```
//This is the Load method
BusinessLogic.Models.ProjectEngineer p = new BusinessLogic.Models.ProjectEngineer(project);
p.IsQualifiedFor(enType, educationEnum);
.
.
.


[UsesRule]
public static void IsQualifiedFor(this Models.ProjectEngineer p, EngineerTypeEnum enType, FieldEducationEnum fieldEducation)
{
    RuleCache.EvaluateRule(p, enType, fieldEducation);
}

.
.
.
public static bool EvaluateRule<TClass>(TClass sourceObj, params object[] parameters)
{
        var frame = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1);
        var methodInfo = frame.GetMethod();
        var atr = methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<UsesRuleAttribute>();
        if (atr == null)
            throw new EISException("You can't call 'EvaluateRule' method in a method that does not have 'UsesRuleAttribute'.");
    ...
}
```

it was working fine in production server until today that I changed something irrelevant. Now the `EvaluateRule` method is throwing exception because it cannot find `UsesRuleAttribute` in caller. and this is the stack trace of the exception:

```
BusinessLogic.EISException: You can't call 'EvaluateRule' method in a method that does not have 'UsesRuleAttribute'.
   at BusinessLogic.Rule.RuleCache.EvaluateRule[TClass](TClass sourceObj, Object[] parameters) in e:\EIS\EISMvc\BusinessLogic\Rule\RuleCache.cs:line 146
   at EIS.Quota.Owner.EngineerList.Load() in e:\EIS\EISMvc\EIS\Quota\Owner\EngineerList.aspx.cs:line 66
```

as you can see `IsQualifiedFor` method call is missing here (it is an extension method). It is working fine when I debug the project in my machine. Is this some kind of optimization or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has likely been [inlined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inlining) by the JIT (Just-in-time compiler), i.e. replaced by its body in the generated native code, so it doesn't appear in the stack.

You can prevent inlining by using the `MethodImpl` attribute:

```
[UsesRule]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void IsQualifiedFor(this Models.ProjectEngineer p, EngineerTypeEnum enType, FieldEducationEnum fieldEducation)
```

Comment: how can I tell JIT to not do it?